# How to integrate $\int \frac{f'(x)}{f^2(x)}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

In my book it states $\int \frac{f^1(x)}{f^2(x)}=-\frac{1}{f(x)}$.
I don't really understand why and it doesn't say in my book.

My first idea was maybe we can cancle out $f^1(x)$. So  $\int \frac{f^1(x)}{f^2(x)} = \int \frac{1}{f^1(x)}$.

But I'm not sure if you can do that and it also doesn't explain the minus from $-\frac{1}{f(x)}$ .

Comment: What does the numbers at the top stand for? So what's $f^1$ and $f^2$. Exponents, derivatives, …

Comment: Sure that's not suppposed to be $\int \frac{f'(x) } {(f(x) )^2 }dx$?

Comment: Perhaps the numerator is $f'$, not $f^1$...

Comment: I guess It could be a typo in the book (wouldn't be the first :/ )

Comment: I guess $\int \frac{f'(x)}{(f(x))^2}$ would make more sense

Comment: But just out of interest what would $\int \frac{f^1(x)}{f^2(x)}$ have been if both are derivatives (first and second)?

Comment: And can you cancle them out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. Let's assume it's a derivative on the top. This comes from the fact that
$$
\left(\frac1{x} \right)'=-\frac1{x^2}
$$ and from using the chain rule:
$$
\left(\frac1{f(x)} \right)'=f'(x) \cdot \left(-\frac{1}{f^2(x)}\right)=-\frac{f'(x)}{f^2(x)}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle \int \frac{f'(x) } {(f(x) )^2 }dx =- \frac{1}{f(x)} + c$,  so is it possible your expression represents that?